# How can I create a new simple symbol, similar to the binomial coefficients?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I was wondering how to make a symbol that looked like $\binom{n}{m}$, except that instead of a bracket, it's a square box around the two symbols. Is this possible? If not, what is the closest I could get? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbinom}[2]{\bgroup
  \fboxsep=1pt
  \fbox{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackanchor{#1\mathstrut}{#2\mathstrut}}}%
  \egroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$y = \bbinom{a}{b}$

\[
 z = \bbinom{12}{7}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!

Comment: Isn't that the wrong size in text-mode? It seems to always be in display-math mode.

Comment: @daleif It is true that in text mode, it does not shrink the object to `\scriptstyle`.  It is for the OP to decide how important that is.  If it were, in fact vital to be used in text mode, I could do a `\mathchoice` to shrink them.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like `\boxed`, but this has the problem that it chooses `\displaystyle` unconditionally.

I suggest a `\styleboxed` macro that boxes its contents, but also allows to set a different value for `\fboxsep`, whose default value seems too big for this application.

You can use `\styleboxed` in any math formula.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\styleboxed}[2][\fboxsep]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{#1}%
  \mathpalette\styleboxed@{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\styleboxed@}[2]{\fbox{\m@th$#1#2$}}

\newcommand{\bbinom}[2]{%
  \kern\nulldelimiterspace
  \kern0.5\fboxrule
  \styleboxed[1.5pt]{%
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}%
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  }%
  \kern0.5\fboxrule
  \kern\nulldelimiterspace
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
m=\bbinom{12}{7}a + \binom{12}{7}a % display
\]
\begin{center}
$m=\bbinom{12}{7}a$ \\ % text
$\scriptstyle m=\bbinom{12}{7}a$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's even better!

Answer (score 0):

That is fairly simple. `\binom` is defined in `amsmath` as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\binom}{\genfrac()\z@{}}
```

thus is made using the `\genfrac` macro. So we only have to replace `()` by `[]`. `\genfrac` is described in more detail in the `amsmath` manual.

End result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbinom}{\genfrac[]\z@{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\bbinom{a}{b}$

\[
 \bbinom{a}{b}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if it's possible for the rectangle to be connected horizontally as well, rather than just blocky brackets (as that's the notation I was planning on using)? This is still helpful and will work if needed though, so thank you.

Comment: @DanielNew define `connected horizontally`? Like a box? Then you probably need to combine a blank `\genfrac` aka `\genfrac{}{}\z@{}` with some other macro.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant! Thank you!